# SVN Clients on Windows Server 2008 R2 freeze while attempting to run update/checkout

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, svn, jenkins

Here's my setup: I'm running Jenkins as a CI build server on Windows Server 2008 R2 VM. My SVN server is v.1.6.[something] on a Linux server (I'm pretty sure it's CentOS, but I don't know the version). Jenkins' SVN plugin is SVN 1.7. I've also tried using TortoiseSVN and SlikSVN (all 1.7) with the same results.

Whenever I try to run an update on a repo, SVN tries to pull the files, but as soon as it tries to get a file from an external, it hangs indefinitely, and I have to force quit the svn client. I've tried completely disabling the firewall, but the same problem occurs.

I did a wireshark capture (which I don't think I should upload since this is a work server), and noticed that every request sent to the SVN server had the error:
`Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x74b6 (may be caused by "IP checksum offload"?)]`

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I should mention that I'm able to pull the files from the repo to other machines without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

This could be network issue or problem with TCP Chimney Offload feature in Windows Server 2008 R2. Try to disable TCP Chimney Offload. Check Chimney Offload feature status using following command:

> netsh int tcp show global

To disable TCP Chimney Offload:

> netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled

You can find more information here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't change anything. :( I'll keep searching for a solution--I'm surprised nobody else has run into this!

Comment: @CullenJ: I recommend you to check network card or network card drivers.